# echo php inside html

Tags: php, mysql, printf, echo

```
$rst=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM flux_receptie WHERE status_procesare ='PRELUAT' AND status_solutionare ='' ORDER BY ora_preluare DESC LIMIT 5");
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($rst)) 
        if(($res)==TRUE)
         echo "
<table class='fixed'>
<td>$res[0]</td><br /><br />
<td>$res[2]</td><br />
<td>&#10148; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;$res[12]</td>
";

?>
```

Is there a way to recreate this code clean? I tried to recreate it, but it does not echo the values from `sql`:

```
$rst=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM flux_receptie WHERE status_procesare ='PRELUAT' AND status_solutionare ='' ORDER BY ora_preluare DESC LIMIT 5");
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($rst)) 
        if(($res)==TRUE)
        ?>

<table class='fixed'>
<td><? print $res[0]; ?></td><br /><br />
<td><? print $res[2]; ?></td><br />
<td>&#10148; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<? print $res[12]; ?></td>
```

Can someone advice me how to make a clean code, please?

Comment: It's not a good practice to use loads of &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; . Avoid them

Comment: Thanks. i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are lot of mistakes in your coding. Improve it First, then Build applications.

```
<table class='fixed'>
    <?php
        $rst = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *
                                    FROM flux_receptie 
                                    WHERE status_procesare = 'PRELUAT' 
                                      AND status_solutionare = '' 
                                    ORDER BY ora_preluare DESC 
                                    LIMIT 5");
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($rst, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $res['database_field_one']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['database_field_two']; ?></td>
        <td>&#10148; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $res['database_field_three']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

> **Listing some of them**
>
> 1. missing argument in `mysqli_fetch_array`
> 2. no use of `if(($res)==TRUE)`, learn about `empty()`
> 3. after `while` loop no curly braces `{}`
> 4. `<table class='fixed'/>` should define top of while loop.
> 5. we never use `<br />` inside table
> 6. all the `<td>`should define inside `<tr>` and .
> 7. we never point data like this `$res[0]`.

Comment: Wow. I am at beginning. I did not expect for so many errors... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

ty this code

```
<?php
 $rst=mysqli_query(
              $link, 
              "SELECT * FROM flux_receptie WHERE status_procesare ='PRELUAT' AND status_solutionare ='' ORDER BY ora_preluare DESC LIMIT 5"
 );
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($rst)) {
?>

<table class='fixed'>
    <td><?php echo $res[0];?></td><br /><br />
    <td><?php echo $res[2];?></td><br />
    <td>&#10148; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $res[12];?> </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class='fixed'>
    <?php
        $rst = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *
                                    FROM flux_receptie 
                                    WHERE status_procesare = 'PRELUAT' 
                                      AND status_solutionare = '' 
                                    ORDER BY ora_preluare DESC 
                                    LIMIT 5");
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($rst, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $res['fieldname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['fieldname2']; ?></td>
        <td>&#10148; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $res['fieldanme3']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```